# Why vue-property-decorator @Watch is not working after route push?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

1. I commit something to store to property `SomeVar`
2. Go to `this.$router.push({name:"SomePage"})`
3. On `SomePage` i have `@Watch` on `SomeVar` and watch is not executing.

`@Watch` is working on `SomeVar` if I commit on `SomePage`.

Code:

1 + 2 

`search_.commitSetSomeVar(store, data);
this.$router.push({name:"SomePage"})`

3. 

`get SomeVar() {
  console.log(search_.getSomeVar(store)) // it is doing console log after route change;
  return search_.getSomeVar(store);
}`

`@Watch("SomeVar")
somefunc() {
  console.log(this.SomeVar(store)) // nothing is logged
}`

Comment: i tried dispatch as well. same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somepage is not active and not executed if it isn't rendered. That's why the watcher does not work. After you route to `SomePage` it get's executed and the watcher does his job.

I do not know your setup, but perhaps you could render the component with v-show?

So it is not always visible but always executed.

Comment: i added a possible solution, but i do not know what you want exactly to do? V-show is most likely not the prefered solution. Perhaps watch within vuex for the change and act there?